# Conectar con firebase. Paso 2. Implementación solicitada obsoleta

Tags: firebase, autenticación

En el Paso 2 del Asistente para agregar autenticación para Firebase me solicita agregar  ´compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'´; lo cual acepto y lo agrega al *gradle* de nivel app como ´implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'´; lo cual, a su vez, genera el error

> ```
> Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0
> ```

Pero aun así me aprueba dicho paso como que está bien, y la dependencia implementada más actualizada para no tener error es:

```
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5') {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
```

pero me desaprueba el paso, como que no lo completé. Estoy usando android studio version stable 3.2.1.

Comment: Proba implementarlo en las dependencias del gradle pero sacandole la ultima parte: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'

Comment: Ya lo hice. Y además hay una nueva versión que es la 16.0.5.  Y a parte si saco la última parte me da lo mismo. Pero olvide algo....el internet permissions....pruebo y te cuento.

Comment: El json que genera firebase lo añadiste a tu proyecto, no?

Comment: Si, lo agregue. Pero el asistente en ese paso insiste que tengo que agregar  **build.gradle will include these new dependencies: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'** . Estoy en version 3.2.1 Stable, el codigo para los gradles tanto de proyecto como de app, y java estan copiados como los tengo en la version canary que no me deja abrir el proyecto porque dice que necesita version 3.4 o superior. Esta version canary no le figura el asistente para conectar con firebase. La version 3.4 no la encuentro para bajarla.

Comment: Sigo teniendo el mismo inconveniente pero no asi para conectar con firebase. Muchas gracias de todos modos por la ayuda!